# Which policy do you follow for maintain your VMs?

Tags: virtualization, vmware-esxi, virtual-machines

Which rules/policy or procedure do you use to maintain your list of VMs?

For ex. Will you assign a VM and keep eyeing on whether it is being utilized or kept idle? (So that you can take it back to pool and give it to some other needy people)

Or Will you assign a VM only for particular period of time and ask the user to request to extend the period?

Comment: This may be too localized...

Comment: Set and Forget.

Comment: Are you talking about virtualized workstations? We virtualize only servers so shutting them down for appearing idle might not be a good idea...

Comment: Depends on the enviroment...so probably too localized. If I created a server and set it up, and then it got "returned to the pool" after a few months I'd be shot. Normally, VM's are, as Tom said above, Set and Forget, unless you're really squeazed on CPU and storage resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only policy that ever worked for me is a fixed deadline for a VM life. I have yet to see a user who ceased to need a system he got hold of...

Comment: No body give it back and says that it is no more needed. Often i am running short of space and not able to meet their vm needs. That's why i tried to adapt some best practices followed by experts. But all are following their own idea it seems.